# How to show that $U = \{u \in \mathcal{L}(E) \mid u + \operatorname{id} \in \operatorname{Isom}(E) \}$ is open?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Let $E$ be a Banach space, and $\operatorname{Isom}(E)$ the set of continuous bijections from $E$ to $E$. We define the set $U$ as:
>   $$U =  \{u \in \mathcal{L}(E) \mid u + \operatorname{id} \in \operatorname{Isom}(E) \} $$
>   Show that $U$ is open.

I attempted two methods, and in both of them I get stuck.

My first instinct was to try to show that the complementary is closed, but by looking at the complementary of the set. In this case we would have:

$$ \mathcal{L}(E) - U = \{u \in \mathcal{L}(E) \mid u + \operatorname{id} \not \in \operatorname{Isom}(E) \} .$$
But it doesn't seem to be easy to show that it's closed.

Secondly, I could show that for any element $x \in U$ there exists $r >0$ such that the open ball $B(x,r) \subset U$. But I am unable to come up with a potential candidate for $r$.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I added the "functional-analysis" and "operator-theory" tags to your post.  Cheers!

Comment: Hint: You might start by showing $U$ is an open neighborhood of 0.  There, if $\lVert u \rVert < 1$, then $1 - u + u^2 - u^3 + \cdots$ converges and forms an inverse to $u + 1$.

Comment: Do you intend for the members of $Isom(E)$ to have *continuous* inverses as well?

Comment: @RobertLewis No, I don't intend them to be continuous as well.

Comment: The open mapping theorem implies that any member of $\operatorname{Isom}(E)$ would *have* to have a continuous inverse.  (The Wikipedia page calls this corollary the "bounded inverse theorem".)

Comment: The proof of this would be similar to the standard proof that for $u \in \mathcal{L}(E)$, the spectrum of $u$, which is defined to be $\{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \mid u - \lambda \operatorname{id} \notin \operatorname{Isom}(E) \}$, is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Daniel Schepler in the comments, an important step is to show that if $\|u\|<1$, then $u+1$ is invertible.  You should try to show this, but if you are unable almost every book on operator theory should contain a proof.

From here, suppose $u\in U$.  Then $u+1$ is invertible (with bounded inverse by the open mapping theorem).  If $v\in\mathcal L(E)$  and $\|u-v\|<\|(u+1)^{-1}\|^{-1}$, then 
$$\|1-(u+1)^{-1}(v+1)\|\leq\|(u+1)^{-1}\|\|u-v\|<1,$$
so $(u+1)^{-1}(v+1)$ is invertible, so $v+1$ is invertble and thus $v\in U$.  Thus $B(u,\varepsilon_u)\subset U$ (where $\varepsilon_u=\|(u+1)^{-1}\|^{-1}$), and therefore $U$ is open.